# Spring JPA Pagination returns wrong resulsts

Tags: spring, jpa

I'm using Property Expressions on a Spring JPA Repository to query entities, paginated.
The first page returns a total number of 6 items, the other pages return the correct total number of 25 items.

Here's a shortened version of the queried entities:

**StoreEntity**

```java
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "store")
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public class StoreEntity extends MyProjectAudit {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    
    @Builder.Default
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = OfferEntity.class, mappedBy = "store", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<OfferEntity> offers = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**OfferEntity**

```java
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "offer")
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="offer_type",
        discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class OfferEntity extends MyProjectAudit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Column
    private Instant validTo;

    @Column(name = "offer_type", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private OfferType offerType;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = StoreEntity.class, optional = false)
    private StoreEntity store;
}
```

**SimpleOffer**

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@DiscriminatorValue("SIMPLE_OFFER")
public class SimpleOfferEntity extends OfferEntity {
}
```

**StoreRepository**

```java
@Repository
public interface StoreRepository extends JpaRepository<StoreEntity, Long> {

    Page<StoreEntity> findByOffers_ValidToIsGreaterThan(Instant validToGraterThan, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Here's the result when querying page 0:
[image]

And here's the result when querying page 1 (and other pages as well):
[image]

**Why does the first page returns a total of 6?**

In fact it should be 25:

[image]

Comment: Don't use `@Data` with entities, it will generate the wrong `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` for entities. See https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/ for a detailed description. Should it be 25? If a store has multiple offers it will return multiple results, so I would expect a distinct in there. You might want to log the SQL generated by Hibernate to see if that matches your expectations.

Comment: Good point. I copied a single dataset pretty often to test pagination. I'll check it today. However, it doesn't explain why the first page returns 6 stores and the next page returns 8 stores. The pagination size mechanism should refer to stores.
btw. I somehow fixes the issue by changing the expression from `findByOffers_ValidToIsGreaterThan` to `findByOffersValidToIsGreaterThan`, (just removing the underscore). The `StoreEntity` has no validTo attribute, so it shouldn't have any effect.

Comment: it doesn't, but you having a OneToMany relationship in the entity that is being eagerly fetched does - this is automatically done as a join in Hibernate, which really messes with pagination. So for each StoreEntity instances, you are getting N OfferEntity instances in the same dataset. Somehow the numbers are that 6 StoreEntity * N OfferEntity brings you to the 25 page limit you've set. Use a different fetch option (lazy, batch fetching) on the relationship to avoid the issue. For the future - check out the SQL actually issued for your query, as it is NOT the count(*) you've issued.